# Google Tag Manager Simple Regex

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

How to create a simple Google Tag Manager Regex Rule

Example

a rule when the URL "contains" a case insensitive string... example

URL: www.mydomain.com/SoMeThING/AnYTHIng

So the rule will fire when the URL has "something" and the example above match... because the regex must be case insensitive...

But to work with "Google Tag Manager"

I tried some web examples, but doesn't seems to work with...

Can somebody help-me?

Comment: If you are comparing to a known example, why use regex?  You can just convert the string `toLowercase()` and then search by `indexOf('string')`.

Comment: GTM supports case insensitive regex matches in your rules/triggers. What are the examples you tried? You can also google a bunch of regex checkers, like https://regex101.com/, for example, to verify your regex.

Comment: Looks like just `/something/i` should suffice.

Comment: Well, it's simple... i don't need to pass a regex formated value... just the value that i want... thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0):

As nyuen mentions, Google Tag Manager supports 4 regex match cases in the trigger configuration.

- matches RegEx
- matches RegEx (ignore case)
- does not match RegEx
- does not match RegEx (ignore case)

In your example you can use.

Page Path - As the Variable.

matches RegEx (ignore case) - As the match case

^/something - As the value.

This will fire the trigger with any page path that starts with /something while being case insensitive.